# Creating new Android project in Intellij: Missing res/values/* xml's by default-Manual add not working

Tags: android, intellij-idea, material-design, android-styles

When I creating in Intellij 14 new Android project, I have only strings.xml & don't have: colors.xml, styles.xml

Why is this?

Also when I added styles.xml manually:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="colorPrimary" type="color">#03A9F4</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark" type="color">#0288D1</item>
    <item name="colorAccent" type="color">#ECEFF1</item>
</resources>
```

and then tried to apply theme on manifest:

```
<application ...
    android:theme="@styles/Theme.MyTheme">
```

I got the following error:

```
Error:Android Resource Packaging: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@styles/Theme.MyTheme').
```

How to fix that? My goal is to have material design with primary, primary dark etc. colors working with API>16 (I'm using appcompat V7 as dependent library project).

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to declare color resources is like this:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#03A9F4</color>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try next code on manifiest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
```

@style not @style**s**